# PHP file handling and third level domains

Tags: php, file, subdomain, unlink

I've a subdomain like software.domain.com that is a redirect to domain.com/software/ through cPanel redirect.
I'm creating an upload system that send all the files in a sibling folder, like domain.com/files/, no problem uploading with some tricks but when it's time to delete that file, that specific script cannot find it...

Returning the $_POST variable send to the script, the path is right, as /files/path/to/file, it refers to the public_html root as it has to be!
The script is invoked using an ajax call, it could be it? Maybe some path translation...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add example code of what you have tried.

Comment: I would recommend storing all path handling code in a common code repository and use it for storing AND deleting. That makes debugging a lot easier. Additionally, you can incorporate different path handling for subdomains more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying your AJAX can't find it from the subdomain, or anywhere else, you need to use the full domain path, WITHOUT the subdomain.

```
var url = "http://domain.com/files/path/to/file";
```

If you're saying your PHP can't find it, you can do something like this to ge the absolute path. From a file in the root of your SUBDOMAIN...

```
$url = realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/files/path/to/file.php";
```

Comment: The second option, my bad... The script is not in the ROOT DIR so i've used `$url = realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/../../files/path/to/file.php";`

Comment: That ain't gonna work. Echo the url to see what it looks like.. that won't create a valid filepath. Everytime you call `dirname()` it moves it up a folder, so the "../" part is not necessary. If you need to move up a level, just add another dirname() call. `realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))`

Comment: Tried it, file_exists and unlink returns both true but the file is still there... Maybe i'll go back to the basic and set the media folder inside the software folder. Thank you!

Comment: unlink returns true AND the file is still there? that doesn't make sense. unlink deletes a file. Something wierd is happening.

Comment: Exactly my thought, BTW moving the folder inside gives no problem and works like a charm! So be it!